# How does Benders son, Ben, remember how to talk without a memory card?

Tags: futurama

In the episode 'The Bots and the Bees' Bender has a son called Ben and discovers he doesn't have the ability to bend because he doesn't have a bending card. To fix this he gets the Professor to switch his memory card for a bending card. Shouldn't Ben have lost his memory of being able to walk and talk?

Comment: It looks like basic functions (walking, talking) are hard-coded (like a BIOS or ROM). After that, we get to the interchangeable memory, which in this case would be anything extra (bending vs memories of his life).

Comment: Good thing he didn't remove his CMOS battery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to walk or talk is hardcoded in the robot - we know this because Ben can walk and talk after the operation but also because he's shown as able to walk/talk without explicit instruction.  The memory card only contains those memories that the robot has made themselves after their creation/birth.

Comment: Does this mean that Ben will not be able to remember the things he learns at bending school?

Comment: I'd imagine those would be written into the bending card.  However he presumably wouldn't be able to remember who the teacher is from day to day, etc.